# Delete Plugin Crash in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I init a plugin using   `plotter = qobject_cast<PlotterInterface*>(plugin);` When i  close application , in `closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` I try to delete plugin with `delete plotter;` but i get crash. If i'm not wrong just objects created with new can be deleted . Why  i get this crash ?

**edit (plug-in import):**

```
QPluginLoader* pluginLoader = new QPluginLoader(pluginDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName)); 
QObject* plugin = pluginLoader->instance(); 
plotter = qobject_cast<PlotterInterface*>(plugin); 
plotter->initPlotter();
```

Comment: How are you loading/importing the plugin?

Comment: QPluginLoader* pluginLoader = new QPluginLoader(pluginDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));

                           QObject* plugin = pluginLoader->instance();

                           plotter = qobject_cast<PlotterInterface*>(plugin);
                           plotter->initPlotter();

Comment: Maybe you are deleting the object more than once? Calling QPluginLoader::unload will automatically delete your object. Are you using that ?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation :

[QPluginLoader::instance](http://grip.espace-win.org/doc/apps/qt4/html/qpluginloader.html#instance)

> ...The root component, returned by this function, is not deleted when the QPluginLoader is destroyed. If you want to ensure that the root component is deleted, you should call unload() as soon you don't need to access the core component anymore...

[QPluginLoader::unload](http://grip.espace-win.org/doc/apps/qt4/html/qpluginloader.html#unload)

> Don't try to delete the root component. Instead rely on that unload() will automatically delete it when needed.

Try using unload and see if the problem persist.

Comment: If QPluginLoader is a temporary value and is destructed in a function,but the root component is assigned to member pointer in another class, how to make sure root component is deleted for sure, and is it necessary to delete the pointer assigned of root component manually?